# MSBUILD : error MSB4166: Child node "2" exited prematurely. Shutting down. Diagnostic information may ... MSBuild_*.failure.txt

Tags: .net, msbuild, msgpack, ilrepack

I am using **MessagePack** to create executables.
However, I want to create one big mpc.exe file that includes the dotnet library.
That file is created by building the MessagePack.Generator.
So I used ILRepack, and it outputs an error message like the one in the title.

I am building a project with the following path

https://github.com/MessagePack-CSharp/MessagePack-CSharp

Following advice from the web, I added the '-nodeReuse:false' option to the build command for the dotnet.yml file in MessagePack.

from : - script: dotnet build -t:build,pack --no-restore -c $(BuildConfiguration) /bl:"$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build_logs/build.binlog -v:d"
to :  - script: dotnet build -t:build,pack --no-restore -c *-nodeReuse:false* $(BuildConfiguration) /bl:"$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build_logs/build.binlog -v:d"

But the build still fails.
The project csproj file we're trying to build looks like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>mpc</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net7.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <ToolCommandName>mpc</ToolCommandName>
    <RollForward>Major</RollForward>

    <!-- NuGet Info -->
    <PackageId>MessagePack.Generator</PackageId>
    <Title>MessagePack Code Generator</Title>
    <Description>MessagePack standalone code generator.</Description>
    <PackageTags>MsgPack;MessagePack;Serialization;Formatter;Serializer;Unity;Xamarin</PackageTags>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ConsoleAppFramework" />
    <PackageReference Include="ILRepack" />
    <PackageReference Include="ILRepack.MSBuild.Task" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" ExcludeAssets="runtime"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build" ExcludeAssets="runtime" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MessagePack.GeneratorCore\MessagePack.GeneratorCore.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="ILRepack" AfterTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <WorkingDirectory>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)</WorkingDirectory>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <InputAssemblies Include="@(ReferencePathWithRefAssemblies)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="MERGING: @(InputAssemblies->'%(Filename)') into $(OutputAssembly)" Importance="High" />
    <ILRepack OutputType="$(OutputType)" MainAssembly="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" OutputAssembly="$(AssemblyName).exe" InputAssemblies="@(InputAssemblies)" WorkingDirectory="$(OutputPath)" Parallel="false" Verbose="true" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

What can I do now?

I tried rebooting, and I tried running a clean build.
And I can't find the diagnostic information named MSBuild_*.failure.txt.